# Where can I find a all avp Pcap for Credit-Control-Request?

Tags: diameter-protocol, ccr

hello everyone if anyone has CCR related pcap file please share with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: pcap example]

Note there are different CCRs for different diameter interfaces. For example CCR for Gx interface will not have the same AVPs as CCR for Gy interface.
However I can not load files to stackOverflow I hope this picture I attached will help you.
In the picture you can see CCR-INIT as described in RFC 4006 for **Diameter Credit-Control Application**

Edit:
Just found this:
[pcap](https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/69f3a4de2b99)

Comment: thanks, buddy it's very helpful for me, can you send me a file on my mail (kamalkumar7234@gmail.com)